# Javascript Insert text inside "<>" input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How i can insert dinamically something like "refer" inside my <> input tag, without writing it directly into html but using javascript?
Something similar to

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setAttribute` for this action

```
var i = document.querySelector("input");

i.setAttribute("name", "myinput");
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have this

```html
<input type="text" value="23" id="age"> </input>
```

You can select that element by

```js
const ageInput = document.getElementById('age');
```

If what you want is to change the text inside you can do this by

```js
ageInput.innerHTML = "Hello World"
```

Or you can set a new attribute by

```js
ageInput.setAttribute("refer", "true");
```

`setAttribute` documentation  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute